# How to show that $A_4$ has exactly one subgroup of order $4$, namely $H=\{i,(1, 2)(3, 4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(1,3)\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> How to show that $A_4$ has **exactly one** subgroup of order $4$, namely $H=\{i,(1, 2)(3, 4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(1,3)\}$.

I have no idea to show this. How to show that there is exatly one subgroup of order $4$ and no more of order $4$.
Please help.

Comment: We like to see questions that show some form of *context*.  This can take the form of showing your work, explaining how you came across the problem, or detailed explanation of what is confusing you.  This helps us help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Can you write down the elements of $A_4$?  Can any of the elements of order $3$ be in a group of order $4$?  What elements are left?

Comment: Elements of $A_4$ are $\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23), (123), (132), (124), (142), (134), (143), (234), (243)\}$. Some of it's subgroups are $\{e\}$, $\{e,(12)(34)\},  \{e,(13)(24)\}, \{e,(14)(23)\} , \{e,(123),(132)\},  \{e,(124),(142)\}, \{e,(134),(143)\},  \{e,(234),(243)\}$, $\{e,(1, 2)(3, 4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(1,3)\}$.

Comment: Please check this and help me to get the answer.

Comment: Please help me to figure out  that this is the only subgroup of order 4 in $A_4$.

Comment: @user1942348 : What does Lagrange's theorem tell you about the preence of elements of order 3 in a group of order 4?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the subgroup $H$ is both Sylow 2-subgroup and normal in $A_4$. Also every other subgroup of order $4$ in $A_4$ is a conjugate of $H$, by Second Sylow Theorem. On the other hand $gHg^{-1} = H$, as $H$ is normal in $A_4$. Therefore if $K$ is any subgroup of order $4$ in $A_4$ we have that there exists $g \in G$ s.t. $gHg^{-1} = K$, but we know that $gHg^{-1} = H$ for every $g \in G$, there for $K=H$ and hence $H$ the only subgroup of order $4$ in $A_4$.

Comment: I dare the downvoter to give me a reason why the answer is wrong and explain his downvote.

Comment: @user26857 Well I agree that using Sylow theorems might be a too advanced of a technique it gives a rather simple solution. I was considering another solution, which is using the fact that if $K$ is a group of order $4$, then $KN$ is a subgroup too, as $N$ is normal, but $\mid KN \mid = \frac{\mid K \mid \mid N \mid}{\mid K \cap N \mid}$, which is either $8$ or $16$, both impossible. But I decided to go with Sylow's Theorem. After all it might spark the OP interest.

Comment: @user26857 From personal experience I learned Sylow's Theorem before my courses even introduced them, as I was interested in them. Anyway back to the downvote. I do from time to time give hints, you can check my answers if you want. But here giving a hint would be almost solving the problem anyway. At the end of the day I'm for MSE to make things like explaining your downvote an obligation and not reduce reputation for this. I think it will lead to better, objective and more quality answers in general.

Comment: @user26857 Also mods would be able to track the reason and delete unjustified downvotes. It might be a huge task, but it's an idea. After all it will protect people from getting those "revenge" downvotes. As for the record I don't even bother with giving you intentional downvotes for the reasons I mentioned (Well explained downvote is better than a upvote). After all when I read an answer it doesn't matter who worte it or not, I just look at the quality of the answers when I give a vote. Anyway for the end I support you view on these issues and keep up the "good work", mate.